# Browser page title in Joomla 3.3.4

Tags: browser, joomla, title, article

i have got following problem with Joomla! 3.3.4: after entering text to the Browser Page Title window in article options, the title doesn't change. In that place is only displayed the global sitename. In older Joomla everything works properly.

Answer (score 3):

To change the field title you need to edit the menu item options.  When you go to the detail view of menu item in question, navigate to the **Page Display** tab.  The first field is **Browser Page Title**, enter the title you want to appear and save.

That should sort it out for you...

Answer (score 0):

Please try to switch to the default template and if it works there is something wrong with your template.

In order to set browser title you could use setTitle() method.

```
<?php
  $this->setTitle( $title );
?>
```

You could check setTitle usage at: [Joomla Docs](http://docs.joomla.org/Customising_the_dynamic_page_title).

If you want to set title in article template you could make an addition to:

```
/templates/*template_name/html/article/default.php
```

An example code that could set the article title to browser title would be:

```
<?php
      $this->setTitle( $this->item->title );
?>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Global Configuration` -> `Site` -> `Include Site Name in Page Titles` and set it to `Before` or `After`. Of course you also have to set a `Site Name`.

[image: Picture for clarification]